# JavascriptExecutor not performing the scroll action

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm automating tests for a youtube video; take this one for instance -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjWfY7SnMBI. 
I want to scroll down the page to check whether comments load. However Javascript isn't executed, scrolling doesn't take place. Test passes as there are no error messages. What could be the cause of this?

I've tried the following:

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, 2500);");
```

Neither works.

```
public void scrolledCommentCount() throws InterruptedException{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    System.out.print("Scrolled");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sendKeys` method to pagedown.Try this code.Hope this helps.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        while(true){

            Long height=(Long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
            System.out.println(height);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.END);        

            if (height==0)
            {
                break;
            }               

        }
```

Comment: What makes you say that window.scrollTo() wouldn’t work? I tested my solution with YouTube and it scrolls down to the comments section just like OP requested

Comment: That's great then.This is another options.

Comment: Thank you both for your input! The first option still didn't work for me (I'm using Chrome) and I'm sure the script got executed because I saw the "Scrolled" print statement from the last method line. However, there was no visible action on the page. I implemented Kajal's solution and I can see the page being scrolled down and comments loading.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like YouTube doesn't set a value for `document.body.scrollHeight` (i.e. it's zero), so that's probably why your first method isn't working. There are several variables used to define the document height and not all sites have values for all of them. The website [here](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window) suggests the following approach for finding the height:

```
window.myScrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

Wrap that command in another `js.executeScript();` method in your Java code. After that you can just call `window.scrollTo(0, window.myScrollHeight);` to make use of the new variable.

If that still doesn't work then I would check to make sure you're actually calling `scrolledCommentCount()`. That could be another reason that the site isn't scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this in python as

```
driver.execute_script("window.ScrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```